# Mermaid CLI - how do you escape characters?

Tags: diagramming, mermaid

I'm using the Mermaid CLI to generate a flowchart (http://knsv.github.io/mermaid/flowchart.html).  It works great, but I can't figure out how to get special characters (percent signs, parenthesis, etc) working as text within a node.

For illustration purposes here is a sample flowchart definition for Mermaid (filename is example.mermaid):

```
graph TD
question1{Gas tank less than 1/8?}
action1[Fill tank to 100%]
question1-- Yes -->action1
```

When I run mermaid on that file, I get this error (it blows up on the percent sign):

```
My-MacBook-Pro:mermaid mark$ mermaid example.mermaid 
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...on1[Fill tank to 100%]question1-- Yes -
-----------------------^
Expecting 'QUOTE', 'TAG_END', 'TAG_START', 'MULT', 'EQUALS', 'PLUS', 'DOT', 'BRKT', 'COLON', 'ALPHA', 'COMMA', 'NUM', 'CLICK', 'CLASS', 'CLASSDEF', 'LINKSTYLE', 'STYLE', 'PIPE', 'THICK_ARROW_OPEN', 'THICK_ARROW_CROSS', 'THICK_ARROW_CIRCLE', 'THICK_ARROW_POINT', 'DOTTED_ARROW_OPEN', 'DOTTED_ARROW_CROSS', 'DOTTED_ARROW_CIRCLE', 'DOTTED_ARROW_POINT', 'ARROW_OPEN', 'ARROW_CROSS', 'ARROW_CIRCLE', 'ARROW_POINT', '==', '-.', '--', 'MINUS', 'DIAMOND_STOP', 'DIAMOND_START', 'PE', 'PS', 'SQE', 'SQS', 'end', 'subgraph', 'NEWLINE', 'TAGSTART', 'TAGEND', 'DIR', 'SPACE', 'GRAPH', 'EOF', 'SEMI', got 'PCT'

  ../dist/mermaid.full.js:14712 in parseError
  ../dist/mermaid.full.js:14782 in parse
  ../dist/mermaid.full.js:13260
  ../dist/mermaid.full.js:16846
  ../dist/mermaid.full.js:16889
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():23 in executeInPage
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():29
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():29
PHANTOM ERROR: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'element.setAttribute')
TRACE:
 -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mermaid/lib/phantomscript.js: 149 (in function resolveSVGElement)
 -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mermaid/lib/phantomscript.js: 69
```

I tried escaping the percent sign, like this:

```
action1[Fill tank to 100&amp;]
```

But then I get the same error on the semicolon.  Any thoughts on how I can escape those characters to make it work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use quotation marks `""` to enclose your text and escape special characters, e.g. in your example:

```
graph TD

    question1{"Gas tank less than 1/8?"}
    action1["Fill tank to 100%"]

    question1-- Yes -->action1
```

will produce this diagram:

[image]

This is now documented in the [official documentation](https://knsv.github.io/mermaid/#special-characters-that-break-syntax).

Comment: This does not seem to work for sequence diagrams? (at least not for ':')

Comment: Sequence diagrams have different syntax https://mermaidjs.github.io/sequenceDiagram.html

Comment: But what if I wanted to add quotation marks *inside* the quotation marks? Do I *then* have to use escape codes, or is there a better way?

Comment: I haven't tried that. But usually can use a single quote inside the double-quote quotation, escape may work too.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with characters like `<` and `>`? I can't get it to work?

Comment: Current link to sequence diagrams syntax:  https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaidjs.github.io/blob/master/sequenceDiagram.md

Comment: For Sequence diagrams if you have `#`, replace it to `#35;`. [entity-codes-to-escape-characters](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/sequenceDiagram.html#entity-codes-to-escape-characters)

Answer (score 13):

Here are more examples of escaping / quoting special characters. The code

````
flowchart LR
  A["For most symbols double quotes are enough: ```~`!@#$%^*()[]{}|\/:;'?<>,.+=-_"]
  B["[&quot;&amp;quot;&amp;lt;&lt;br&gt;&amp;gt;&amp;amp;&amp;frac12;#35;189;&quot;]"]
  B --> C["&quot;&lt;<br>&gt;&amp;&frac12;#189;"]
````

produces
[image: Mermaid flowchart]

Using this method most unicode characters (including non-ASCII) can be included using either unicode entity or markdown `#code;` syntax (both ways are illustrated using the character ½ in the diagram above). See also the [official documentation](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/./flowchart?id=special-characters-that-break-syntax).

Disclaimer: I didn't test it in Mermaid CLI. Tested in [markdown-viewer](https://github.com/simov/markdown-viewer) and [Mermaid live editor](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/edit#pako:eNpFj0tPhTAQhf_KOCq-QPflim9XrnRJUQoMj6Sl19LG3CD-douCLk7OyeScL5kRS10RMqyl_ihbYSw8PfMe4Cbl-KgNKD1YGHaq0HKASrtCErw7bWkAYQio165pGeR5_pXvXe8fHL6eHp-k2Th9cn7B4qOrTRKen11GbxyzmXvruWkwE-JAqG38n6R3r8IEzXJZfdbvJFspEEUJ3HnWgvLDTWGSv-lPD0NUZJToKv_gOO842pYUcWQ-VlQLJy1H3k--6raVsPRQdVYbZLWQA4UonNUvu75EZo2jtXTficYItbSmb6ova00).

Answer (score 1):

That was an issue with early mermaid versions. I tried your example code with mermaid 0.4.0 where it renders fine. I would recommend upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

sequenceDiagram syntax are different.
Refer to official document:
https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/sequenceDiagram.html#entity-codes-to-escape-characters

```
Entity codes to escape characters It is possible to escape characters using the syntax exemplified here.

Code: mermaid sequenceDiagram
    A->>B: I #9829; you!
    B->>A: I #9829; you #infin; times more! A B I ♥ you! I ♥ you ∞ times more! A B Numbers given are base 10, so # can be encoded as
#35;. It is also supported to use HTML character names.

Because semicolons can be used instead of line breaks to define the markup, you need to use #59; to include a semicolon in message text.
```